# Extracting Info from Ghidra Listing Window

Tags: disassembly, ghidra

I have written a script which extracts all the assembly code from a PE using this code in ghidra

```
instructionList = []
for instr in currentProgram.getListing().getInstructions(True):
    instructionList.append(instr)
```

but the issue is that, is changes all the .DLL calls in the assembly code.
For example, if the listing window shows

```
CALL        dword ptr [->MSVCRT.DLL::signal]
```

The output I get is

```
CALL dword ptr [EBP + -0x14]
```

Is there a way to get the assembly code exactly as it is in the listing window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the answer was provided in the OP's [ticket #1994](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/1994), just transferring it here for the future seekers:

```
from ghidra.program.model.listing import CodeUnitFormat, CodeUnitFormatOptions
codeUnitFormat = CodeUnitFormat(CodeUnitFormatOptions(CodeUnitFormatOptions.ShowBlockName.ALWAYS,CodeUnitFormatOptions.ShowNamespace.ALWAYS,"",True,True,True,True,True,True,True))

instructionList = []
for instr in currentProgram.getListing().getInstructions(True):
    instructionList.append(codeUnitFormat.getRepresentationString(inst))
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this after I read the post but couldn't find a way to make it neat and clean

just recording the thought process as pawel created an answer that is nice

```
>>> inst = currentProgram.listing.getCodeUnitAt(currentAddress)
>>> print (inst,inst.getReferencesFrom()[1])
(CALL qword ptr [0x1c0007050], ->NTOSKRNL.EXE::EtwRegister)
```

edit a regex substitute hack is what I was thinking of before abandoning it like below

```
>>> re.sub("\[.*\]",'['+inst.getReferencesFrom()[1].toString()+']',inst.toString())
    u'CALL qword ptr [->NTOSKRNL.EXE::EtwRegister]'
```